# Jquery: Не получается получить value из input radio, загруженных другой функцией

Tags: jquery

Собственно, методом post

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#registerButton').on('click',function(){
 var lot1 = $('#text').val();
 $.post(
    'obrabotchik.php', // адрес файла с обработчиком
    {lot:lot1},
      function (data){
       $('#otvet').html(data);
});
});
})
```

получил выборку радиоинпутов

```
<input type="radio" id="inputReg" value="One">
<input type="radio" id="inputReg" value="Two">
```

Необходимо при выборе радиокнопки сразу передать значение в следующую форму.

```
<input type="text"  id="GR" value="Значение радиокнопки">
```

Хотел применить следующую функцию

```
    $( "#inputReg" ).on( "click", function() {
        //копирование значения радиокнопки в форму
       ( "#GR" ).val( $( "input:checked" ).val());
    });
```

Она срабатывает только если радио инпуты были на странице изначально, но подгруженные игнорирует.

**Как изменить последнюю функцию для копирования значений из подгруженного объекта?**

Comment: Метод "on" будет навешивать события и на динамически добавленные элементы. Почему у вас несколько элементов с одним id? Попробуйте использовать имя класса вместо id, id должен быть уникальным на странице.

Comment: Таким образом (один id) я отделяю пакет радиоинпутов. Есть и другие... Меня интересует значение только одного инпута со значением checked.

Comment: @Xstroy id - это уникальный идентификатор, элементы на странице должны быть с уникальным `id`. Отделять пакет вы можете например одним классом. А выделяются элементы в группу по одному имени.

Comment: Мне кажется, без разницы, что будет якорем для функции.

Comment: Вижу у себя в примере, что действительно id были разными, на там событие вешалось на все инпуты. Как правильно указать name?

Comment: @Xstroy для группы `<input type="radio">` `name` должно быть одно и тоже, а `id` могут быть с цифрой, например `<input type="radio" name="test" id="inputReg1" value="One">
<input type="radio" name="test" id="inputReg2" value="Two">`

Comment: Это ясно, но как в функции указывается ссылка на name. id - это #inputReg1, class - это .imya_classa, а как правильно name обозначить?

Comment: @Xstroy это уже на Ваш вкус) логично назвать `inputReg` если на странице больше нет элементов с таким именем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для динамически создаваемых элементов следует вешать событие на *document* или *body*

```js
$(document).on("click", ".inputReg", function() {
  //копирование значения радиокнопки в форму
  $("#GR").val($("input:checked").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="inputReg" class="inputReg" value="One">
<input type="radio" name="test" id="inputReg" class="inputReg" value="Two">

<input type="text" name="GR" id="GR">
```

P.S.: в данном случае правильнее вешать событие на класс, однако если Вам нужно все же повесить событие на `id`, то код также будет работать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47707/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-jquery----value--input-radio).